# Printing from a Linked List(Java)

Tags: java, printing, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I'm getting an unwelcome output while printing from a specific linked list, I already have two lists populated and I can print from them without any problem. However with this one specific list it gets printed after every iteration with the previous data that has been stored in it (I know its supposed to happen if you're returning a list but I want to change this) For example if a number after manipulation was 1000 and the second number returned after manipulation should be 2000 my output for the second one would be 10002000. If anyone can tell me what boneheaded problem I'm having I'd be grateful. Also if I need to show the code I can.

Comment: If you include the relevant code as well as the expected and actual output, you might get some help.

Comment: Most likely you have a bug in your code, and the first thing you should do is to try to debug it with your debugger to see why it is producing this number. my guess is you are either not resetting a buffer, or you should be producing `1000, 2000` but you are not printing a separator between the numbers.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Its too long to post this is just one sub function of the code but essentially that's it I'm trying to declare the list to null after every iteration so it only collects new data and dumps the old. Its supposed to print the 1000, then dump it, then print 2000 etc. On new lines too but the 10002000 arent supposed to co-exist within the list. Idk if I'm making sense.

Comment: So I would assume you are not clearing when you think you are you are print both numbers without a separator. I still think you need to use your debugger to see why this is happening.

Comment: Which IDE are you using?

Comment: JCreator Pro, and hey @PeterLawrey I found the error after a little while of debugging, it was simply re-initializing the list to null at the wrong place, I had to do it within the first loop in the method, I was doing it in the second. Thanks all.